# comparing the difference of two random variables with a value

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution

Suppose I have random variables $X$ and $Y$, both are normally distributed. $X$ has mean $a_1$ and variance $b_1$, and $Y$ has mean $a_2$ and variance $b_2$. Is there a way to test whether $X-Y$ is significantly different from zero?

Comment: Please specify your attempts thus far

Comment: What does it mean "$X-Y$ to be significantly different from zero"? $X-Y$ is a random variable, and will never take on a value of zero.

Answer (score 2):

If X and Y are independent then $X-Y$ is normal with mean $a_1-a_2$ and variance $b_1-b_2$. You can calculate, for a given $\delta$, the probability that $X-Y$ is greater than $\delta$ or less than -$\delta$ where you define "significantly different from 0" to mean that $X-Y$ is at least $\delta$ away from 0.

Note that if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent there is no solution unless you specify the correlation.